# How to write a query in MS Access to sort out the records that overlap other record's time period?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an intermediate table as in below

```
Ref#    |Time                   |id
--------------------------------------
10      |10/23/2020 6:48:03 PM  |9
10      |10/23/2020 6:53:56 PM  |12  <-- target output record
10      |10/23/2020 7:53:56 PM  |9
12      |10/23/2020 7:48:03 PM  |11
12      |10/23/2020 7:55:56 PM  |11
```

My goal is to sort out any different id that fall into other id's timeline given the same Ref#. In the above case, id 12 is overlapped the time period of id 9. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you seem to want anything that is between the times of another id.  So, I am thinking:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t as t2
              where t2.ref = t1.ref and
                    t2.id <> t.id
              group by t2.id
              having t.time > min(t2.time) and
                     t.time < max(t2.time)
             );
```

Or this might be more efficient using `group by`:

```
select t.*
from t inner join
     (select ref, id, min(time) as min_time, amx(time) as max_time
      from t
      group by ref, id
     ) as tt
     on t.ref = tt.ref and
        t.id <> tt.id and
        t.time > tt.min_time and
        t.time < tt.max_time;
```